# usage function doesn't work with getopt

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, getopt

I have a problem with a usage function in Python. This is a part of my main function:

```
def main(argv):
    try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hi:o:tbpms:', ['help', 'input=', 'output='])
            if not opts:
                    print 'No options supplied'
                    usage()
    except getopt.GetoptError,e:
           print e
           usage()
           sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
                    usage()
                   sys.exit(2)
if __name__ =='__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

and I define a usage function as well

```
def usage():
    print "\nThis is the usage function\n"
    print 'Usage: '+sys.argv[0]+' -i <file1> [option]'
```

but when I run my code as `./code.py` or `./code.py -h` (it is executable) I got anything but the Python help.

Comment: What do you mean by "anything but the python help"? What exactly is the output in each of those situations? Your code appears to be correct.

Comment: `usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...`

Comment: You're going to need to show us more code. I don't see what is triggering the Python usage line in what you've pasted.

Comment: I ran your script after making it executable and adding #! /usr/bin/python to the top of file. It calls the usage function just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below worked for me.  Run it with "python code.py".

```
import getopt, sys

def usage():
  print "\nThis is the usage function\n"
  print 'Usage: '+sys.argv[0]+' -i <file1> [option]'

def main(argv):
  try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hi:o:tbpms:', ['help', 'input=', 'output='])
    if not opts:
      print 'No options supplied'
      usage()
  except getopt.GetoptError,e:
    print e
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

  for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
      usage()
      sys.exit(2)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: "I didn't get an error" isn't an answer to "why did I get an error".

Comment: @agf Yes, that's true.  This is here in case his real goal was to get working code.  If he's only interested in learning why his code didn't work, I suppose this isn't as helpful.

Comment: thanks for your help, removing the `-` from `if opt in ('-h', '--help'):` seems to work for me... THANKS

Comment: +1 for answer but I do not get why you have 'tbpms:' short opts. They are not being used anywhere nor do they have any corresponding long opts from what I read.